# Asked to replicate an issue with certain version of Ubuntu. Which ISO should i download?

Tags: system-installation

I have been asked to replicate an issue on a server.  The info I was provided is: Linux version 3.16.0-23-generic , (gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)).

Can someone explain which ISO I should download to begin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By googling `gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)` you will find [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/amd64/gcc-4.9-base/4.9.1-16ubuntu6) page. From there you can see that this is from version 14.10 Utopic Unicorn. You can download the appropriate image (desktop/server, 32bit/64/bit etc) from [there](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/utopic/).

With the info you shared I think you want the 64bit server image which according to the mentioned page is [this](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/utopic/ubuntu-14.10-server-amd64.iso).

Comment: Thanks for the Help. I did find version 14.10 on a search but wanted to be sure.  Thanks for the verification.

Comment: You 're welcome. Please click the answer as accepted so any other user with the same problem knows that this answer worked for you.